# SQL Updating only from previous day

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have loaded all the content from TableA where TableA has a field called

```
CreatedDate(DateTime)
```

I have copied only the content of this table which are of actually usefulness.

Rather than using SQL Agent to schedule a job to copy this table everynight, I would like to append the data and only insert any new data added and perhaps do some updates that may have been affected in last day.

Just wondering whats the best way to do this taking into account we already have the initial data loaded but just want to append new data each day.

I was thinking about doing the following SQL in the where clause:

```
CreatedDate between getdate()-1 and getdate()
```

Is this the best way to do it?

Thank you

Comment: Can you get the `MAX(CreatedDate)` of the previous run?  If you can, you can use that in your where clause, something like `CreatedDate > MAX(CreatedDate)`.

Comment: AS wdosanjos pointed out taking MAX(CreateDate) of your target table will help you identify your Lower range and then using GETDATE() as upper works.  The only thing is this will help you identify NEW records but you mention wanting to look for changes too, can records be updated?  If so you need a version indicator or another column that indicates that Perhaps something like UpdateDate, does 1 exist?  Afterwords 2 operations Update and Insert fairly easy and though I don't recommend it personnal as there can be complex issue with it MERGE() can also be used

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly the kind of situation that SSIS is built for. Essentially you want to load only new data every day and in the ETL process this is known as an [incremental load](http://www.tutorialgateway.org/incremental-load-in-ssis/).

The best way of accomplishing your desired outcome is to create an ETL, have it only grab data where MaxDateTime > CreatedDate (or ModifiedDate assuming you have that column and you want to include updates to previous data). If your CreatedDate doesn't change if previous data is modified, then you would need to add a lookup and conditional split to go through the data.

Then you would create a SQL Agent job to run the incremental ETL daily.